# httpd redirect one port number to another

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, httpd.conf

We are trying to redirect requests on port 8555 to port 8443. In our httpd.conf file, we have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:8555>
SSLEngine on
# SSL configuration that is irrelevant to this question

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:8443%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when a user goes to `https://example.con:8555/foo`, they get redirected to `https://example.com:8555:8443/foo` instead of `https://example.com:8443/foo`. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTP_HOST` contains the value set by the "Host:" request header. You could try using `SERVER_NAME` instead, which contains the value of the `ServerName` directive, if configured in your VirtualHost block. Otherwise httpd tries to find the ServerName via reverse DNS.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8443%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Another option, if you only have one server name you can just write it in the RewriteRule directly, you don't have to use variables for this.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com:8443%{REQUEST_URI}
```